# Smallest positive number with the following format

Tags: floating-point, type-conversion, decimal, signed, twos-complement

12 bit floating point number: 1 bit sign, 4 bit exponent, 7 bit significand.

The significand is normalized so that the first digit to the right of the radix point must be a 1.
Exponent is signed 2's complement.
No bias for the exponent. No implied bits for the significand.

### What is the smallest positive number for the 12 bit number and also the decimal number it represents?

Regarding the exponent, in unbiased 2's complement, I know the smallest 4 bit negative number is 1000, which is -8 in decimal.

The smallest significand is 1000000.

Therefore, the 12 bit number I got was 0 1000 1000000.

The problem I have is, when converting this number to decimal, is it

[ 1 (base 2) x 2^-8 = .00390625 ]      or is it     [ .1 (base 2) x 2^-8 = .001953125 ]?

I think it's .001953125. Am I correct, or is it .00390625?

Thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

The smallest positive number using your 12 bit representation is: 2^(-8) = 0.00390625.
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Normalized_notation

Comment: Thank for the fast answer! However, as stated in the question, there is no implied 1 to the left of the significand. Are you still claiming, without the implied bit, 0 1000 1000000 is still 2^(-8) = 0.00390625?

Comment: Yes. Because the significand bits still represent the number 1 in this case. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Normalized_notation

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks so much. The page, [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand#Examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand#Examples), about the significand also confirmed this. To quote, depending on the interpretation of the exponent, the significand can represent either an integer or a fraction.